# Install PloneBooking into Plone

Tags: plone

Hello I'm trying to install PloneBooking Product into my Plone 4.3.3 by using buildout.cfg like this

```
eggs =
    Products.PloneBooking
    Products.PloneFormGen
    Products.ZMySQLDA
    Plone
    Pillow
```

Automatically I can see the PloneFormGen into my plugins page but no sign of PloneBooking, It could've be a version issue. I've already tried using mr.developer and using the github version, but the documentation is confusing since there's no [eggs] into my buildout.cfg in this link http://plone.org/documentation/kb/installing-add-ons-quick-how-to
. How can I proceed from this point?

Thanks already.

Comment: Are there any errors in the log when running buildout or startup?

Comment: oh thanks for pointing that out, I just started fg and it showed an error "Import Error: cannot import name i18n" I've searched a bit about it and there's no clear solution for this problem.

Comment: More of the traceback would be useful, but it says i18n can't be imported from some particular module: the odds being that it's now in a different module.

Comment: I've came to the solution, the default version is not compatible with plone version, so I've put PloneBooking into [versions] PloneBooking = 3.0.0a2 Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's a python version problem in some modules, so I've just installed a different version of PloneBooking into my [versions] section, like:

```
Products.PloneBooking = 3.0.0a2
```

no need for mr.developer or anything.

Comment: You should approve your answer.

Comment: yeah i kinda forgot because 6 hours is a lot of time to remember to approve